# Ubuntu 10.04 Rails deploy - Why is capistrano failing to deploy to server?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am trying to deploy with capistrano. RVM is installed on the server and the ruby version is 1.93p385.

Here is the log of cap production deploy:

http://pastie.org/private/vs336nrgejpwdkuelufnma#

Why is capistrano failing to deploy?

Here is the deploy file:

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "1.9.3-p385"
set :rvm_type, :user #Should the user by the username?
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"

set :http_server, :apache2
set :rake, "#{rake} --trace"
set :application, "app"
set :user,        "myuser" # The server's user for deploys

set :ruby_version, "1.9.3-p385"

set :scm,         "git"
set :repository,  "my git repo here"

set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache

set :use_sudo,    true

default_run_options[:pty]   = true # Must be set for the password prompt from git to work
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :nodejs, true

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

The server is an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

```
** [out :: server] No such file or directory - /var/www/app/releases/20130216170229/config/database.yml
```

Does this path exist on the server? You might need to create the `/var/www/app/releases` portion by hand, which capistrano will then deploy into.

Comment: The git repo is set to ignore the database.yml. But I have seen other realeases with the database.yml. How to setup the database.yml when deploying to production so that is included in the app on production. If the database.yml is caussing the problem.

Comment: The absoulte path does not exists, but I have `/var/www/app/releases` or `root/var/www/app/releases`

Comment: Why would you git-ignore the database.yml? If your app uses a DB, how do you expect it to be configured?

Comment: Because some people don't want their DB password in git repo, and people may also have different database.yml. I will do some research on this subject, think it is possible to do a capistrano task that create a database.yml for the project. Ryans bates did recommend it in one of his screencasts..

Comment: There are various ways of keeping passwords out of git (one is to use environment vars in database.yml, like ElasticBeanstalk/EC2 does), but I think you have found your immediate problem.

Comment: I will approve your answer if the database.yml is the problem. Just need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common pattern to `.gitignore` `database.yml` for capistrano deployment. The database config then resides in `<:deploy_to>/shared/config/`. The you use this cap task to symlink the db config in your release directory:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end

  desc "Symlink shared folders on each deployment"
    task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end

before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:symlink_shared"
```